# Overriding CSS style in aspx page (inline)

Tags: asp.net

I'm having this difficulty of overriding a table data style  where the main css file text-transforms the first letter into uppersize. Any idea if I can stop this right in my aspx page (inline)? Thanks.

Comment: post you HTML page and CSS

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to the element's inline style.

`text-transform:none !important;`

Comment: Thanks. However, I tried adding this but it didn't work:
style= "text-transform:none !important"

Comment: @bmc-cpu Well then, I'm going to have to see more code to help :)